# Count and groupby dates using multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I have an excel spreadsheet simplified to the sample below. Each 'Person ID' will have a 'Created Date' and a 'Link Date'. I can't figure out how to get 'Person ID' counts grouped by month & year with the following conditions:

- if 'Created Date' and 'Linked Date' are the same month, the 'Person ID' counts as 1 for that month.
- if 'Created Date' and 'Linked Date' are different months, the 'Person ID' counts as 1 for each respective month.

Sample Input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GoLN.png)

Sample Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw6Ep.png)

I added columns for 'CreatedYear-Month' and 'LinkYear-Month' to easily groupby, but can't figure out how to account for 'Person IDs' that have different months for 'Created Date' and 'Link Date'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4u8U.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely want to do this in Python, you should look into the documentation for pandas dataframes. You can filter the data by multiple conditions like this:

```
import pandas

dataframe = pandas.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
filtered_data = dataframe.loc[(dataframe['Created Date'] == "17/10/2021") & (dataframe['Link Date'] == "21/10/2022")]
```

Check out the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html